# Dictionary<myField, myObject> where myField is a member of myObject

Tags: c#, hash, hashmap

Is it possible in C# to create a dictionary made up of objects, such that the `Key` is only a reference to the value of the field (or a field of `Value`, as it were), so that it is guaranteed that `index == myDictionary[index].myField`?

For instance, imagine a standard C# `Dictionary`. Suppose I have `Car` objects:

```
class Car {
    string name;
    int wheels;
    double weight;
    double horsepower;
    double topSpeed;

    // Appropriate constructors
}
```

Which I want to store in this Dictionary, indexed by name:

```
var cars = new Dictionary<string, Car>();

var newCar = Car("Ford", 4, 2387.4, 4535.7, 128.2);
cars["Ford"] = newCar;
```

My criterion is not guaranteed, because I can do:

```
cars["Ford"].name = "not Ford";
```

And the condition is broken. I can simply remove the `name` field from `Car`, but then the car itself would not know its own name - an embarrassing situation to be in for a car, in this day and age, even if we set aside the performance cost.

So my question: Is it possible to easily make a hash map in C# such that the value of the hash is always equal to some part of the hashed element, and the hash is updated whenever the element is?

Comment: `hash is updated` If you are already stored in a hash table... how exactly would you propose this should work? It sounds like a dictionary might not be the structure you want.

Comment: The hash is supposed to be immutable for any object. It must be based on the fields that defines the identity of an object. The same that are tested in the `Equals(object)` method. You must not change the hash otherwise, you won't be able to find your key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) class, but you'll have problems if you change an item's key after you have added it to the collection.

If you want to have a hash collection that handles changes to its elements identifying properties, you could implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the type (`Car` in your example), and have the collection reposition items (or remove and re-add them) as needed.  It would be inefficient and terribly prone to bugs.

Comment: That's an `abstract` class. Could you explain how exactly would you use it in this case?

Comment: @svick by deriving a concrete class from it, same as any abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Indexers in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Comment: Indexers might be useful, but this is not the answer to this question. How exactly would you use indexers?

Comment: @svick If you look at the class TempRecord example in the link. I was thinking if that could be used as Dictionary

Comment: Please may i request to explain -1

Comment: Like I said, this is not an answer to the question. The `TempRecord` your mentioned does something completely different. And normal `Dictionary` already uses indexers, you didn't say anything about how could indexers help solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider to change the class design to :

```
class Car { public string name { get; private set; } }
```

Thus, you won't be able to change the part of the that identifies the object. Otherwise, the dictionary seems to be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be to construct your own designated `CarDictionary` with a string based indexer along the following lines (assuming that the `Name` field/property is `public`):

```
public class CarDictionary : List<Car>
{
    public Car this[string name]
    {
        get { return this.Single(car => car.Name.Equals(name)); }
        set {
            var oldCar = this.SingleOrDefault(car => car.Name.Equals(name));
            if (oldCar != null) base.Remove(oldCar);
            value.Name = name;
            base.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public new void Add(Car car)
    {
        if (this.Any(c => c.Name.Equals(car.Name))) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Dictionary already contains a Car with the same name");
        base.Add(car);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you would need to re-implement or hide other base class methods such as `AddRange`, `Remove` etc. to ensure that the collection is not accidentally corrupted.

If you now initialize your car "dictionary" and add the *Ford*:

```
var cars = new CarDictionary();

var newCar = new Car("Ford", 4, 2387.4, 4535.7, 128.2);
cars["Ford"] = newCar;
```

the dictionary state is:

```
Number of cars: 1, name of first car: Ford
```

If you then try:

```
cars["Ford"].Name = "not Ford";
```

the dictionary state will be:

```
Number of cars: 1, name of first car: not Ford
```

Next, using the re-implemented `Add` method to add a new *Ford*:

```
cars.Add(new Car("Ford", 6, 4000.0, 500.0, 100.0));
```

will yield the following dictionary state:

```
Number of cars: 2, name of last car: Ford
```

Trying to add another *Ford* using the `Add` method will yield an exception:

```
var anotherFord = new Car("Ford", 3, 1000.0, 50.0, 120.0);
cars.Add(anotherFord);

InvalidOperationException: Dictionary already contains a Car with the same name
```

but if you use the indexer instead, the new *Ford* will replace the old:

```
cars["Ford"] = anotherFord;

Number of cars: 2, name of last car: Ford
```

Finally, one peculiarity with using the indexer to add a new `Car` to the dictionary is that the indexer potentially could (should?) change the name of the added `Car`:

```
cars["thought this was a Ford?"] = anotherFord;

Number of cars: 3, name of last car: thought this was a Ford?
```

As far as I can tell this would be the expected behavior of the indexer setter. If this behavior is undesired, simply remove the line

```
value.Name = name;
```

from the indexer setter implementation.